# Deleting All Lines In Notepad++ Except Lines With :00 :05 :10 :15: 20: 25 :30 :35 :40 :45 :50 :55 :60

Tags: notepad++

How do I perform the action in Notepad++ of deleting all lines except lines with different terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the search dialogue and select the **Mark** tab. In the **Find what** field enter a search string to find the lines to be kept. The question is not really clear, should those strings be at the start of the lines or the end or anywhere in the lines. Enter either `^:(([0-5][05])|60)` or `^:(([0-5][05])|60)$` or `:(([0-5][05])|60)` respectively. Make sure that **Bookmark line** and **Regular expression** are selected, then click **Mark all**. Next visit the menu => **Search** => **Bookmark** => **Remove unmarked lines**.

The search strings look for a colon followed by some digits. The digits can be either any of **012345** followed by any of **05** or they can be explicitly **60**. Note that **65** is not required hence the simpler regular expression `:[0-6][05]` cannot be used.

Comment: Thanks! Working now! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can always use regex in the find-replace, something like

```
^[^:][^0-6][^05]
```